# TortoiseSVN v1.8.6: Delayed Timing Between Commits and Updates

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, delay, commit, lag

My team recently moved from Visual Source Safe to Subversion (SVN). We use TortoiseSVN v1.8.6. Our code base is in .Net (Visual Studio 2013, .Net 3.5), and is about 1.6GB.

We have been experiencing issues with SVN not downloading all of the latest changes when updating. For example, a developer committed a change one afternoon. 30 minutes later, 2 other developers got the latest from SVN. They did not get the first developer’s changes. When these 2 developers got latest again the next morning, the changes were there. We’ve tried clearing the folder from a local computer, checking out again with “Fully Recursive” selected, and it doesn’t seem to make a difference.

We also randomly received SQLite and I/O disk errors when committing or updating SVN. Our office location is 1 of 3 in the USA, and we are the only office with these strange behaviors. I’m not sure if these errors are related to the first problem or not.

Has anyone else experienced this “lag” or delay time between a commit and update? Could this be as simple as an SVN setting? Or does this sound like a network issue?

Answer (score 1):

Contact the system administrator who is responsible for your Subversion server and tell him about the behavior. I guess that you have some [write-through proxy (master-slave repository replication)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.writethruproxy) implemented in your organization and the replication is the bottleneck causing the lag you've mentioned. In such case you can't do anythihing on client-side to fix this. Contact your system administrator.

Comment: Thanks, I'll touch base with them.

Answer (score 0):

It's pure network or infrasrtucture issue (and, BTW, offtopic here)

It's also can be somehow broken or damaged Working Copies (test, repair or create at least one new /better 2/ on checked HDD /or new host/)

Show real output of **CLI-test** here (svn commit + svn ls -v URL + svn up)

Comment: On Friday afternoon, we tried "svnadmin verify", and got the following message:
E165005: Expected repository format '3' or '5'; found format '12'.

I'm curious if we've corrupted our repository when converting from VSS to SVN-to maintain history. We used an open source tool (VSS2SV). Ran it against a VSS folder or entire database, and it extracted it from VSS and put it into a local SVN repository (created a local one just for the conversion; not connected to the prod SVN server). Then we created a dump file from the SVN repository, and imported the dump file into the prod SVN server.

Comment: We tested the commits (UI, not CLI) on Friday, and couldn't reproduce the delays. It's sporadic, and maybe when there's heavy traffic on the server.